# Can I change the default movement speed when ordering a unit to move in a battle?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

Whenever I'm in a tactical (land) battle and I order a unit to reposition itself somewhere the men eagerly start running there.

As I usually don't want to tire the men at the start of a battle, I then have to manually click the movement speed button to have them walk to the new position instead?

Is there anyway to set the default movement speed for a unit to walking instead of running?

Comment: There is, you just right click for them to move. What you are doing is right clicking and dragging this will force them to run. But if you have locked your groups in the positions you want and just right click they will start walking there. Now i've noticed that it is not to bad these days for them to run since most of the battles i've had were quite short ranged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is.

When you click once, they walk; when you double click, they run.

However, when you click and drag in order to have them face a particular direction, they will run by default; to **make them walk instead**, keep the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button on your keyboard pressed before releasing your mouse button.

Also worthy of note: if you click and drag while they are *hidden*, they will walk by default; so if you want them to run, you'll have to toggle running (press <kbd>R</kbd> on the keyboard). This only applies if your army is actively hiding, e.g. in a forest, *not* if not in view of enemy units, e.g. on the other side of a hill or behind the city walls.